# Is Compound Index on a collection is always better than having single Indexes

Tags: mongodb

I have come across this particular line with respect to indexes in mongdb .

**Each additional index on a collections does impose some overhead when performing inserts or updates that involve changing index entries.**

which means that with respect to  my understanding , if there are more number of indexes on a collection it will degrade performance during insertion or Updation .

So is it always true that compound indexes are always better than single indexes ??

For example if i have a collection named stocks

and a compound index is present on it as shown below

```
db.stocks.ensureIndex({"symbol":1,"date":1,"type": 1,"price":1},{"unique" : false})
```

and the above  is better than the individual indexes shown below .

```
db.stocks.ensureIndex({"symbol" : 1}, {"unique" : false})
db.stocks.ensureIndex({"date" : 1}, {"unique" : false})
db.stocks.ensureIndex({"type" : 1}, {"unique" : false})
db.stocks.ensureIndex({"price" : 1}, {"unique" : false})
```

Please let me know if i am correct or not ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I depends upon your queries, currently MongoDB can only use one index per query and index intersectioning is still on the road map ( https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3071 )however that being said compound indexes work via prefixes. As an example if you were to:

```
db.c.ensureIndex({s:1,d:1});
```

That index would work for a query with `s` and `d` or only `s` but not using only `d`. So compound indexes are not always the best method.

You have also got to consider:

> Each additional index on a collections does impose some overhead when performing inserts or updates that involve changing index entries.

depends on the size and type of indexes your updating, not just how many indexes you have. For example updating an index containing large text areas will be very slow.

This also applies to updating a large compound index compared to two smaller indexes for example.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation , i was following this particular  link http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/  , so if i have 5 fields indexed on a collection , i cannot go with querying based only on the last indexed field . I know that explain will clarify me the results but don't want to take a chance with  the production environment .

Comment: @PreethiJain Precisely, you can only go on the prefix of the compound index

Comment: thank you very much , i was confused with this whats does  prefix of the compound index  exactly mean here ?? Prefix means  Is it the only first filed of that index or is it the  order that is followed ?? Thanks in advance .

Comment: @PreethiJain Prefix is about what fields in teh query and the order in the index, for example if the index is `{a,b,c}` in that order, `a,b` and `a` would be prefixes but `c` would not, you cn query by any order of `a,b` and `a` and use the index but not of `c`

Comment: Ok , i followed the concept with your help . So is it advisbale to create two indexes on the collection as shown db.c.ensureIndex({s:1,d:1,e:1});
and also 
db.c.ensureIndex({s:1});  to suit my current requirement ?? whats your advice ??

Comment: @PreethiJain It depends on what other queries you have going, I only know the bare bones about your scenario, akax one query.

Comment: thank you very very much for clearing all my questions i had earlier . It was really great knowledge transfer .

Answer (score 0):

No. As of `MongoDB v2.6` with its support for [Index Intersection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-intersection/) it really depends on how you query your data because:

1. Compound indexes are usually bigger than single indexes, and so take more time to update.
2. Compound indexes only support all the index fields or a prefix while single ones support every subset of fields in any order.

If you always query using all the index fields then it's better to use a compound Index, otherwise I would rely on index intersection and the freedom it brings.